# Import mixed graph from Excel

Tags: graphs-and-networks, import, excel

I am new to Mathematica. I want to use the software as it allows analysis of **mixed graphs** (directed and undirected edges).

I have my network as an Excel spreadsheet of three columns: *source*, *target* and *directed*. The names of the nodes are in *source* and *target*, and whether the edge between them is directed or not (*directed* = 0 or 1).

Please could someone explain how to import this data into a mixed graph format in Mathematica?

Thank you,
James

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.Stackexchange! There isn't going to be a solution like `Import["file.xls", "UndirectedDirectedGraph"]` if that's what you think. You will have to create the graph after you've imported the data (as a list of lists), so try to do that and if it you can't get it to work please ask a question with details about what you have tried and include sample data.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the file `datagr.xls` contains your data, import it using

```
importeddata = Import["datagr.xls"][[1]];
```

and construct the edge list using `Apply (@@@)`

```
edgelist = {DirectedEdge, UndirectedEdge}[[1 + #3]][#, #2] & @@@ importeddata
```

alternatively,

```
edgelist = If[#3==0, DirectedEdge[#,#2], UndirectedEdge[#,#2]]& @@@ importeddata
```

or `Map`

```
edgelist = If[#[[3]] == 0, DirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]], 
              UndirectedEdge[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] & /@ importeddata
```